# How to get text from an OptionMenu when I press a button (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `menu` tab in my tkinter window, when I press Upload months option, it calls `upload_months` function, and then an OptionMenu appears with a button.

I just want every time I press that button get the option that is in the OptionMenu even if it changes its option.

My code is:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')

menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

def upload_months():
    months = ["January", "Feb","Mar"]
    variable = StringVar(root)
    variable.set('Choose')

    w = OptionMenu(root, variable, *months, command=callback)
    B = Button(root, text ="Send", command = get_optionMenu_selection)
    w.place(x=20, y=10)
    B.place(x= 105, y=11)

def callback(selection):
    return selection

def get_optionMenu_selection():
    value = callback(None)
    print(value)

filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Upload months", command=upload_months)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open")
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
root.mainloop()
```

In `callback()` I tried to return the value of the OptionMenu, so it can be recieved in `get_optionMenu_selection()` and saved into `value` so I can print `value` every time I want, but it doesn´t work.

My window looks like this:

[image: first one]

And every time I press `Send` I would like to get the text so in console looks like this:

```
January
Feb
Mar
Mar
January
...
```

Instead of that I just get in console every time I press `Send`:

```
None
None
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was the source of the error:

```
def get_optionMenu_selection():
    value = callback(None) ### this returns None
    print(value)
```

in fact, you don't need the callback function because you are using a button. you only need to pass the variable to the `get_optionMenu_selection` function.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')

menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

###the other function was removed

def get_optionMenu_selection(variable): ###this changed
    print(variable.get())

def upload_months():        
    months = ["January", "Feb","Mar"]
    variable = StringVar(root)
    variable.set('Choose')

    w = OptionMenu(root, variable, *months)
    B = Button(root, text ="Send", command = partial(get_optionMenu_selection, variable)) ###this changed
    w.place(x=20, y=10)
    B.place(x= 105, y=11)


filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Upload months", command=upload_months)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open")
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you are passing `variable` as an argument, why are you globalizing it.

Comment: oops, sorry that was a test from before passing the variable, will edit the answer now. thanks